# How to compare multiple arrays, when ID is the same, remove that array and update the original array with +1 to quantity in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to create a "Cart" page that shows products that have been added to the cart.  Currently i am displaying anything that gets added to the cart via a foreach loop that loops through an array of products.  If i add the same product again, it shows twice.  I'd like to remove the duplicate product and update the quantity field by 1.

For example, the products array would look like this...

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 222
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 333
        [quantity] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 222
        [quantity] => 1

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 444
        [quantity] => 1
        
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 222
        [quantity] => 1
        
    )
```

What would be the best way to remove the duplicate products that have matching product ids, and update the quantity key by 1?  So product id 222 would have a quantity of 3.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share yhe code? The requirement is pretty straight forward. In your loop which adds the product into cart array, check whether the product id already exists and increment the quantity on it instead of adding it again.

Comment: Don't do it like that.  Maybe use an array like `[444 => 1, 222 => 1]` then you can just add 1 to 444 etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an associative array it is pretty simple:

```
$input = [
    [
        "product_id" => 222,
        "quantity" => 1
    ],
    [
        "product_id" => 333,
        "quantity" => 1
    ],
    [
        "product_id" => 222,
        "quantity" => 1

    ],
    [
        "product_id" => 444,
        "quantity" => 1
    ],
    [
        "product_id" => 222,
        "quantity" => 1
        
    ]
];

$output = [];

foreach($input as $row) {
    if (array_key_exists($row["product_id"], $output)) {
        $output[$row["product_id"]]["quantity"] += $row["quantity"];
    }
    else {
        $output[$row["product_id"]] = [
            "quantity" => $row["quantity"]
        ];
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: You the man!  Thank you!  The only thing i would like to add to this is the $output was missing the product_id in each array.  But when i added "product_id" => $row["product_id"] above "quantity" => $row["quantity"] in the else statement that added the id back to each array.

Comment: You are welcome. The `product_id` is the key in the associative array `$output`.  Try `foreach ($output as $key => $value) {var_dump($key.":".$value["quantity"]);}`